# Problematic differences in scrape and flatten brushes between 2.79b and 2.8x

Tags: sculpting

I have used Blender for years for 3D scan cleanup, but I'm having trouble migrating to 2.8x. My two main brushes are scrape and flatten, which help me remove hair, stubble and noise mainly. In 2.79b I get very smooth surface geometry without altering the shape or structure of the face. The scrape tends to take the tops off of the stubble and leaves the surrounding geo untouched (unless I keep going at it). The flatten brush usually finishes it off by removing the final noise and smoothing out the surface regardless of its underlying topology.

However, with 2.8x it is entirely different and I haven't been able to figure it out. I created a quick video of the process and the problems. I start in the old version of blender where you can see me take out stubble and other skin problems. After that I flatten it out slightly and I end op with the person's skin without any noise. However, when I jump to Blender 2.8 I cannot seem to take out just the stubble. In fact, I find that mostly the surrounding geometry is affected and not so much the peak I'm trying to get rid of. The flatten brush seems to just make the surface lumpier rather than flat. In both versions I'm working with the default settings and no the brushes aren't inverted.

https://youtu.be/Aolsw7F6Suo

It's about 2 minutes long, boring and without sound. It wasn't meant to be exciting. Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, 
Jan

Edit: Here's an example on a simple surface with some peaks on it. Both versions with default settings and similar brush size.

[image: difference in scrape results between 2.79 and 2.8x]

Comment: Hi. While videos *can* be good, ideally all question content should be present in the body of the question in the form of good descriptions and images. External links may break at some point, making this question unclear to people who could answer and to people who have the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Question: can you copy the brush in 2.79b and rename it, saved to file, and append that brush in 2.8 and see if it comes in with the same behaviors you are looking for? I just wonder if the append will allow the whole brush to come in or if it will just slap settings onto the equivalent brush in 2.8x.

Comment: Craig -> I've tried appending the brush. I can go through the motions but I don't see the brush appear in Blender 2.8x. It's not that they share the same name (Scrape/Peak vs Scrape) so it can't be that.